# Plotly two overlapping funnels: the code isn't working

Tags: python, plotly

I want to visualise two overlapping funnels: blue (wider one) and red. I want the blue
one to have legends, numbers, axis invisible. So i tried this code (which is not working):

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
   

trace=go.Funnel(
    name = 'all',
    y = ["all leads", "not junks", "warms", "hots","deals"],
    x = [317379,304725,11476,3194,2163],
    textposition=None,
    marker={'xaxis': {'range': [0.2, 1],
                      'showgrid': False,
                      'zeroline': False, 
                      'visible': False}})


trace1=go.Funnel(
    name = 'web',
    y = ["all leads", "not junks", "warms", "hots","deals"],
    x = [281316,269490,10252,2508,1602],
    textposition='outside',
    marker={"color": '#dc143c',"colorscale": 'Hot',"colorbar": {"bgcolor": None}})

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(trace)
fig.add_trace(trace1,secondary_y=True)

fig.show()
```

getting an error: Bad property path

The problem is with:

```
marker={'xaxis': {'range': [0.2, 1],
                      'showgrid': False,
                      'zeroline': False, 
                      'visible': False}})
```

I don't know how to fix, but i need it to make the blue one's legends, numbers and axes invisible. Without this the code is working, but returning this result:
[image]
Which is not smth i expect as it is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, there is just a few edits needed to your code:

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
   
trace=go.Funnel(
    name = 'all',
    y = ["all leads", "not junks", "warms", "hots","deals"],
    x = [317379,304725,11476,3194,2163],
    textposition=None,
    showlegend=False,
    marker={"color": 'blue'}
)

trace1=go.Funnel(
    name = 'web',
    y = ["all leads", "not junks", "warms", "hots","deals"],
    x = [281316,269490,10252,2508,1602],
    textposition='outside',
    marker={"color": '#dc143c',"colorscale": 'Hot',"colorbar": {"bgcolor": None}})

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(trace)
fig.add_trace(trace1, secondary_y=True)

fig.layout.yaxis.update(showticklabels=False)
fig.layout.xaxis.update({'visible': True})

fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace: trace.update(ids=[]) if trace.name == "all" else (),
)

fig.show()
```

Legend is removed for the blue/wider funnel chart with `showlegend=False`. Blue color is set for that chart with the `marker=` argument. y-axis is removed for that plot with `fig.layout.yaxis.update(showticklabels=False)`. (You could remove the labels for the other y-axis with `fig.layout.yaxis2.update(...)`.) And numbers are turned off for that plot with `fig.for_each_trace(...)`.

X-axis is also turned to visible with `fig.layout.xaxis.update({'visible': True})`.

[image]

Comment: I tried to have subplots of several overlapped funnels, and my code isn't working. Can you please check it as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72287337/plotly-create-subplots-out-of-overlapping-funnels-whats-wrong-with-my-code . Thank you!